# Convert drawable to bitmap and modify its color

Tags: android, bitmap

Because I need my drawable as bitmap descriptor, I convert my resource to a `Drawable` then to a `Bitmap`.

But I want to change its color, So I used the following code found somewhere here:

```
private static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
            return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        }
    }

    if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
    } else {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

    int iColor = Color.parseColor("#006f00");

    drawable.setColorFilter(iColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

But the drawable's color remains black.
Can you please tell me why and how to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

This converts a BitmapDrawable to a Bitmap.

```
Drawable d = ImagesArrayList.get(0);  
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
```

And for changing bitmap's color see below link

[How to change Bitmap image color in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699810/how-to-change-bitmap-image-color-in-android)

Comment: class cast exception in BitmapDrawable.

Comment: @Ramani : Please give more details regarding it. What have you tried ?

Comment: i will use FontIconDrawable.inflate(context, R.xml.ic_red_marker) and create drawable but when i run app it will crash in BitmapDrawable line say classcastexception

Comment: The  code only works if **d** already is a BitmapDrawable, in which case it's trivial to retrieve it as a bitmap... Will crash with ClassCastException in all other cases.

Comment: you have any idea about my code? how to get bitmap. actually i have to set map marker bitmap or resource or etc. i want to set thi"FontIconDrawable.inflate(context, R.xml.ic_red_marker) " in marker

Comment: Please give some more code so that i can understand what you want to do ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95639/discussion-between-ramani-and-kishudroid).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP`, the method you use for apply the filter. I don't know specifically SRC_ATOP but this [link](http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html) explains all of them.

I don't know how your image is composed, but I'd use `DST_ATOP` instead of `SRC_ATOP`.

EDIT: I presumed that this code won't return in the case you are analizing, 'cause if it returns the filter obviously is never reached.

```
if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) 
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
    if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
        return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Paint p = new Paint();
ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(Color.RED, 0);
p.setColorFilter(filter);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, p);
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert drawable into bitmap use this -

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                       R.drawable.icon_resource);
```

You can change bitmap pixels color by this-

```
int[] pixels = new int[myBitmap.getHeight()*myBitmap.getWidth()];
myBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());
for (int i=0; i<myBitmap.getWidth()*5; i++)
    pixels[i] = Color.BLUE;
myBitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());
```