# Android - Applying color to black and white image

Tags: android, filter, colors

I have a transparent black and white image. I would like to apply specific color (say red) to the black portion of the image and leave white portion of the image as it is. How do i achieve this with Android mobile?

Thanks

Comment: You need to be far more specific.

Comment: This is the sample image http://i63.tinypic.com/206h6qw.jpg. In this picture i would like to change the black color to red color. I have tried the solution mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699810/how-to-change-bitmap-image-color-in-android. They all change the white color also to red color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the color filter of imageview to LightingColorFilter (Color.White, Color.Red) provide the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your pic on some view / layout. You can achieve your goal by changing, setting background color on the view / layout under your image. 
(on the view under half transparent image).

Example

```
 yourViewUnderPic = findViewById(R.id.yourLayoutID);
 yourViewUnderPic.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#006400"));
```