# Convert an Image to Red Scale using Android Studio

Tags: android

I want to convert an image in to Red Scale. But I don't know How to convert. Please help me how to convert an image taken from gallery or camera  into Red Scale using Android Studio?
package com.example.tayyabamaryam.greenscale;

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b1;
    ImageView im;

    private Bitmap bmp;
    private Bitmap operation;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.green) ;
        im=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img) ;

        BitmapDrawable abmp = (BitmapDrawable) im.getDrawable();
        bmp = abmp.getBitmap();
    }
 public void red(View view) {
        operation = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(),bmp.getHeight(),bmp.getConfig());

        for(int i=0; i<bmp.getWidth(); i++){
            for(int j=0; j<bmp.getHeight(); j++){
                int p = bmp.getPixel(i, j);
                int r = Color.red(p);
                int g = Color.green(p);
                int b = Color.blue(p);
                int alpha = Color.alpha(p);

                r =  r + 150;
                g =  0;
                b =  0;
                alpha = 0;
                operation.setPixel(i, j, Color.argb(Color.alpha(p), r, g, b));
            }
        }
        im.setImageBitmap(operation);
    }


}
```

android× 1051320

Comment: Please show your code or what you've attempted so far.

Comment: Why do you insist on using AS for that? Any good pixel editor enables you to do that.

Comment: @LeopoidJoy See my code

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/18695325/5049244