# Converting png to drawable, then colorfilter, then bitmap - not working

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, drawable, porter-duff

I have a png consisting of white and gray (both alpha 100%) and fully transparent areas (alpha==0). 
I'm trying to tint the icon in different colors and then return a bitmap. This is my code.

```
        Drawable iconDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(iconDrawableId);
        iconDrawable.mutate().setColorFilter(0xffff00ff, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        Bitmap outputBmp = ((BitmapDrawable) iconDrawable).getBitmap();
```

Unfortunately my icon stays white and gray. What am I overseeing?

Comment: The color filter on a `Drawable` is only applied when it is drawn. It doesn't alter the underlying `Bitmap`. If you want to tint the `Bitmap`, you'll have to do something like is shown at the top of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31970565).

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike. Your comment helped widening my horizon in the area of Drawables, Bitmaps and Canvas ... and then the fix was easy

Answer (score 0):

After Mikes hint I realized that I could do it like this:

```
        Drawable iconDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(iconDrawableId);
        iconDrawable.mutate().setColorFilter(0xffffff00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(iconDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), iconDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        iconDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        iconDrawable.draw(canvas);
```

But in the end I went for this

```
        Bitmap whiteBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), iconDrawableId);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
        Bitmap bitmapResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(whiteBmp.getWidth(), whiteBmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapResult);
        canvas.drawBitmap(whiteBmp, 0, 0, paint);
```